# No-U-Turn Sampler (NUTS) for handling class imbalance

Tags: bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, unbalanced-classes, bambi

I have a dataset of about 100 records and about 80% of those records belong to one class. The rest belong to another class. I'm building two Bayesian models (logistic regression and multiple linear regression) with the Bambi python library which runs the NUTS algorithm for approximating the posterior distribution of the model parameters. How well does the NUTS algorithm handle class imbalance? I'm curious about this because I'd like to know whether I should be employing some other techniques.

Here is a little bit more information about the model. The model I'm building is attempting to predict election outcomes for each county in a specific state. The logistic regression model output a binary value of 0 or 1, representing democrat or republican. The goal is to use a trained model on previous election years to predict out-of-sample election results from a year that was not part of the training dataset.

Comment: Welcome to CV, Harrison.  It depends on the details, but in many such circumstances this would neither be considered much of an imbalance or it might even be totally irrelevant, depending on the role your class plays in your models.  Please feel free to edit your post to include more information about that.

Comment: I've updated my post to include more information about the model. I'm not sure if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I think you should consider how class imbalance can affect logistic regression since that's the model you're using. NUTS is the sampling algorithm used to find the posterior, and it behaves quite well for (linear) regression models.